# Could anyone direct me to a good Java sound guide?

Tags: java, audio

I am currently trying to make a metronome with adjustable rhythm and tempo, but I have no idea how to use the Java sound API.

Comment: Oh wow, these are great resources.  Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [demo](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html) on Oracle's website for the Java Sound API. Also be sure to check out the [Java Sound Programmer Guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/sound/programmer_guide/contents.html).